# special matrix name (similar to cyclic matrix)

Tags: matrices, limits, supremum-and-infimum

does the matrix that follows the following condition have a special name?

#### Setting

$$A=(a_{ij})$$
$$a_{ij} ∈ R$$

#### Notation

$$A^2=A*A=(^2a_{ij})$$
$$A^n=(^na_{ij})$$

#### condition

$$ \forall a_{ij} ; k∈R $$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(|^na_{ij}|)<k$$

There is a bunch of matixes that fullfill that condition
e.g. E; cyclic matixes; "asymtotic" Matrixes e.g. all a_ij <1

i'm hoping to find the general name so that i can check the lemmas and theoremes for something helpfull

Comment: If $A=(a_{ij})$ then $A^n=(a^n_{ij})$ is bad notation.

Comment: changed position of index